# Python for loop scope

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to format a dictionary variable to use as a report.  I want to recurse through the dictionary and concatenate the items from the dictionary into a formatted string that will be printed/emailed out to users.  I'm having issues getting with the string variable (*text*) losing some of the text concatenated to it.

What I want is:

```
first \n
\t status: first did not have any updates to apply \n
second \n
\t status: first did not have any updates to apply \n
```

My function is:

```
def formatReport(report, text = ""):
  for x in report:
    if isinstance(report[x], dict):
      text += "{0} \n".format(x)
      formatReport(report[x], text)
    else:
      text += "\t{0}: {1} \n".format(x, report[x])
  return text
```

When I call:

```
report = {'first': {'status': 'first did not have any updates to apply'}, 'second': {'status': 'second did not have any updates to apply'}}
formatReport(report)
```

I get (note the order of the output is not important to me):

```
'second \nfirst \n'
```

After adding a ton of debugging:

```
def formatReport(report, text = ""):
    for x in report:
        print "before if: " + text
        if isinstance(report[x], dict):
            text += "{0} \n".format(x)
            print "if: " + text
            formatReport(report[x], text)
        else:
            text += "\t{0} : {1} \n".format(x, report[x])
            print "else: " + text
    return text
```

I have narrowed the issue to down to the fact that the *text* variable is losing the string appended after the *else*.  ie on this line:

```
text += "\t{0} : {1} \n".format(x, report[x])
```

So the output of the debugging code after the *else* is run the first time in the first *for loop* looks like:

```
else: second 
    status : first did not have any updates to apply
```

When it loops back to the top of the *for loop* is looks like:

```
before if: second
```

From what I have read for loops and if/else statements do not have their own scope as Python does not have block level scoping.  I'm at a lose here I have tried all kinds of different combinations or variable names, parameters, etc....  It's worth noting I want to run this code on dictionaries that are 3+ levels deep, hence the need for the recursive call in the *if* statement.

Comment: You aren't assigning the return value of `self.formatReport(report[x], text)` anywhere.

Comment: Wow, I'm blind, thanks